# In vue test utils $refs is set to an empty object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, vue-test-utils

I'm mounting a component `EditUser` in tests using the `mount` function from `vue-test-utils`. `EditUser` has one child component `ChangePassword`. `mount` should mount all child components as is and not stub them. I'm accessing the `ChangePassword` components `submit` method using a `ref` like this `this.$refs.changePassword.submit()`. It works fine in browser but in test `$refs` is getting set to an empty object and can not access the submit method. I'm using jest to test my `vue` components.

In `EditUSer.vue` component

```
updatePassword() {
  this.$refs.changePassword.submit()
    .then(data => {
       this.successMessage = data.message
       this.$bvModal.hide('change-password-modal')
     })
     .catch(data => {
       console.error(data.message)
      })
}
```

In template

```
<b-modal id="change-password-modal" title="Change Password" size="lg" @ok="updatePassword">
    <change-password ref="changePassword" :id="id"></change-password>
</b-modal>
```

And in `ChangePassword.vue` component I have a submit method

```
submit() {
  return this.form.patch('/api/users/' + this.id + '/password')
}
```

In test

```
it ('updates password', async () => {
    moxios.stubRequest('/api/users/1/password', {
      status: 200,
      response: {
        message: 'Password updated successfully!'
      }
    })

    const wrapper = mount(EditUser, { propsData: { id: 1 } })
    const testUtils = new TestUtils(wrapper)

    wrapper.vm.updatePassword()

    await flushPromises()

    testUtils.see('Password updated successfully!')
  })
```

It works fine in browser but in test (jest) I'm getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined

      262 |       },
      263 |       updatePassword() {
    > 264 |         this.$refs.changePassword.submit()
          | ^
      265 |             .then(data => {
      266 |               this.successMessage = data.message
      267 |               this.$bvModal.hide('change-password-modal')

      at VueComponent.updatePassword (src/Users/EditUser.vue:264:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/unit/users/editUser.spec.js:64:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using Vuetify's v-dialog. I'm not familiar with BootstrapVue, but I think the issue stems from how Vue itself sets up the $refs.

$refs won't be updated until the bound component is created, and Vue will wait to create the component until it needs to be rendered.

To get around this, just make sure your change-password component has been rendered at least once in your test before trying to access $refs.

In your test, try something like

```js
wrapper.vm.$bvModal.show('change-password-modal'); // should render the content, binding $refs.
await wrapper.vm.$nextTick(); // make sure Vue has time to update
wrapper.vm.updatePassword();
```